# Cycle through open internet explorer tabs

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

How can i cycle through all internet explorer tabs leaving each one open for 10 seconds.Searching Google doesn't appear to have any example.

So to clarify i have c# code which opens up internet explorer with 6 tabs with various webpages. Now i want my program [winform] to cycle trhough each open tab.

Comment: With what? Console app? Using Selenium? Way too broad.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault i have clarified the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer does not have any public tab APIs. You can use [accessibility APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to activate (IAccessible::accDoDefaultAction with CHILDID_SELF) tabs (they are [child windows of the main directui window](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/03a8c835-e9e4-405b-8345-6c3d36bc8941/ie7-ie8-tab-interaction-accessibility-class?forum=ieextensiondevelopment)) but keep in mind the [accessibility tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741931%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not documented and could change between IE versions (e.g. IE6 does not have tabs in its accessibility tree).